# Change the ordering in bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I would like to change the ordering (swap) of the last two references.
The ordering I following is to use the surname's letters of the first author. So, shi > song.

I am not using biblatex. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: here]

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example so we can replicate your problem?

Comment: In addition to editing your query to show the 3 bib entries in question, do please akso revael which bibliography style you employ. Are you allowed to switch from an alpha style to an authoryear citation style?

Comment: I am using bibliographystyle alpha. @Mico

Answer (score 1):

With original BibTeX the sorting is defined by the used BibTeX `.bst` style file, e.g., `alpha` uses an alphabetic sorting order of the authors, editors etc.

If you need a different sorting order as the one provided by the used BibTeX style file, you have to either find another `.bst` style file or change the used `.bst` style file.

A good choice is the use of [`custom-bib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib).  The included master BibTeX style file `merlin` defines many options for citation, sorting order etc.

If you want to continue using the currently selected BibTeX `.bst` style file you have to change it to your special needs. Please be warned, that the BibTeX style file programming language uses the nowadays unusual UPN or postfix notation (like PostScript or Forth)! An assignment in infix notation `a := 1` is coded in postfix notation as `1 'a :=`: write the arguments first, followed by the assignment operator.

For more infos how to program BibTeX style files see ["btxhak" - Designing BibTeX Styles](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf) by Oren Patashnik.

To change your used BibTeX style file make a copy of the `.bst` file, assign another name to your local copy.  Then open the new `.bst` file with a text editor, search for the command `SORT`.  Before this command you will finde the definitions of all functions creating the BibTeX internal sort keys.  Usually a sort key is calculated by iterating over all read entries with a call of `ITERATE{presort}` preceding `SORT`.  The iteration function `presort` can have a different name.  Search this function definition to see that it calls various other functions to extract parts of the author, editor, title, and various other fields in a bibliography entry and finally assigns the resulted sort key to the internal entry variable `sort.key$`.  Now you have to search for the function extracting the name of the author or authors and how these names are used, or truncated, and/or combined - done in a function using the BibTeX internal function `format.name$`.  This sort key helper function has to be changed accordingly to your needs.